# Traveling with two passports

Tags: schengen, egyptian-citizens, kuwait, bosnian-citizens

Egyptian passport holder, living in Kuwait, on Kuwait residence, also Bosnian passport holder.
Traveling to Schengen, going out of Kuwait with Egyptian because of Kuwait residence in it, entering Schengen with different passport.

Comment: No, it should not be a problem. The airline might want to see your Bosnian passport as well (to verify that you don't need a Schengen visa) but you can still show another one to the Kuwaiti authorities.

Comment: I've downvoted you as it's not clear what your question is.

Comment: Have a [tour](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tour) first and write a proper question. There's no question in your question

Answer (score 4):

Here is your procedure:

1. At the check-in counter at Kuwait - show your Bosnian passport (otherwise, you won't get your boarding pass).
2. At Kuwait immigration, show your Egyptian passport - otherwise you won't get authorization to leave; this is the passport that will be stamped with your exit out of Kuwait.
3. At the departure gate, show the Egyptian passport.
4. At arrival at your destination, show your Bosnian passport - because this is your authorization to enter the country. They (may or may not) stamp this passport - this depends on the individual procedures at the port of entry.
5. When you are on your flight back to Kuwait, show the Egyptian passport with the Kuwait resident visa stamped to get your boarding pass.
6. At the immigration/exit point - show your Bosnian passport if it is required to be stamped with any exit stamps (again, if required).
7. At arrival in Kuwait, show the Egyptian passport to immigration for your entry stamp.

Comment: (+1) I have heard anecdotal reports of border guards failing to stamp passports correctly but if you are entering the Schengen area on a Bosnian passport, they *should* do it, the rules are quite clear.

Comment: I entered and exited Iraq without any stamps on my passport at all - go figure :/

Comment: Oh, I meant in the Schengen area…